# Names for types of URLs

Tags: html, http, url

1. **Absolute**
   `http://www.example.com/images/icons.png`
2. **Relative**
   `../images/icons.png`
3. **???**
   `/images/icons.png`
4. **???**
   `//www.example.com/images/icons.png`

Do [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) types 3 and 4 have names? One place I've seen type 4 being used is on [Slashdot](https://slashdot.org/).

Comment: @Esko: Browsers seem to understand type 4. I think they are useful for when you serve both from http and https and you want to have the same html source files but with absolute references.

Comment: @Esko except for the fact that it is **not** malformed...

Comment: @Colargol If you see my response, that is also document-relative.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

1. **Absolute** http://www.example.com/images/icons.png
2. **Document-Relative** ../images/icons.png
3. **Root-Relative** /images/icons.png
4. **Protocol-Relative** //www.example.com/images/icons.png

For #4, I've also often called them "Protocol-Agnostic"

Comment: @Alnitak All terminology is made up. What's important is everyone uses the same terminology so we can communicate.

Comment: @IanNewson I think you just made my point for me.  The terminology used here is _not_ the same as everyone else uses.

Comment: @Alnitak I agree with you, I upvoted your answer. My criticism is that your comment doesn't criticise this answer for the right reasons.

Answer (score 45):

Type 1 is just a "URI" (sometimes called an "absolute URI").

For types 2, 3 and 4 the definitive answers are in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-27), section 4.2.

They are all "relative references", but according to the RFC are qualified thus:

- `../images/icons.png` - "relative path reference"
- `/images/icons.png` - "absolute path reference"
- `//`...`/icons.png` - "network path reference"

The latter is often used if you want to specify a URL containing a domain name, but where you want the protocol to match the protocol used to access the current resource.  For example, if your images are downloaded from a CDN, you could use this to default to `https` if the current page was also downloaded via `https`, thus preventing the warning about including non-secure resources in a secure page.

Answer (score 7):

number 3 is also considered relative. number 4 is absolute, but lacks the protocol. This is useful, if you want to be able to access the same URL using HTTP and HTTPS.

**Absolute URLs** specify the location of a Web page in full, and work identically no matter where in the world you are.

**Relative URLs** are context-sensitive, giving a path with respect to your current location.

Comment: except that per RFC 3986 (cited in Alnitak's answer), #4 is *not* "absolute" in the sense the spec uses that word.

Answer (score 1):

Type three is **root-relative**.

Dunno about 4.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute Url gives out directly the location of the file/document you are looking for.
example:"http:/www.otagasue.com/images/coolpics.jpg"
Relative Urls normally points a file/document in relation ti the current location of the file.unlike absolute thet are short urls referring to root directory
example"...otagasue/pica.jpg"

frm otaga.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question. Could you refer to the example the OP has given?