# Technical terminology - URL Paths types: Absolute, relative, and

Tags: url, path, terminology, relative-path, absolute-path

I understand that an absolute path is of the type:

```
http://www.example.com/thisdir/4/5uy3/2/s.js
```

and also, that relative paths are of the type:

```
5uy3/2/s.js (in relation to directory "4")
```

but what is the term for the type of path that is prepended with a slash to reference back to the root? For example, if someone was working on a script in `s.js`, he/she might use `/thisdir/4/5uy3/2/s.js` when including that javascript from different directories to avoid having to consciously think about the current working directory when including it. 
Do you know what this type of path is called?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Types of URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743247/types-of-urls)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Dreamweaver / About linking and navigation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7c44a.html)

> There are three types of link paths:
>
> - Absolute paths (such as http://www.adobe.com/support/dreamweaver/contents.html).
> - Document-relative paths (such as dreamweaver/contents.html).
> - Site root–relative paths (such as /support/dreamweaver/contents.html).

The term "application root" would be the same as "site root" except that the site must be an application.

Comment: There is also protocol relative URLs.
e.g. //www.adobe.com/support/dreamweaver/contents.html