# Is a URL with // in the path-section valid?

Tags: http, url, cookies, session-cookies, rfc3986

I have a question regarding URLs:

I've read the [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) and still have a question about one URL:

> If a URI contains an authority component, then the path component
>   must either be empty or begin with a slash ("/") character.  If a URI 
>   does not contain an authority component, then the path cannot begin
>   with two slash characters ("//").  In addition, a URI reference
>   (Section 4.1) may be a relative-path reference, in which case the
>   first path segment cannot contain a colon (":") character.  The ABNF
>   requires five separate rules to disambiguate these cases, only one of 
>   which will match the path substring within a given URI reference.  We 
>   use the generic term "path component" to describe the URI substring
>   matched by the parser to one of these rules.

I know, that `//server.com:80/path/info` is valid (it is a schema relative URL)

I also know that `http://server.com:80/path//info` is valid.

But I am not sure whether the following one is valid:

```
http://server.com:80//path/info
```

The problem behind my question is, that a cookie is not sent to `http://server.com:80//path/info`, when created by the URI `http://server.com:80/path/info` with restriction to `/path`

Answer (score 68, accepted):

See [url with multiple forward slashes, does it break anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161177/url-with-multiple-forward-slashes-does-it-break-anything), [Are there any downsides to using double-slashes in URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256190/are-there-any-downsides-to-using-double-slashes-in-urls), [What does the double slash mean in URLs?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8354/what-does-the-double-slash-mean-in-urls/8381#8381) and [RFC 3986 - Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986).

Consensus: browsers will do the request as-is, they will not alter the request. The `/` character is the path separator, but as path segments are defined as:

```
path-abempty  = *( "/" segment )
segment       = *pchar
```

Means the slash after `http://example.com/` can directly be followed by another slash, ad infinitum. Servers might ignore it, but browsers don't, as you have figured out.

The phrase:

> If a URI does not contain an authority component, then the path cannot begin
> with two slash characters ("//").

Allows for [protocol-relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743247/types-of-urls), but specifically states in that case no authority (`server.com:80` in your example) may be present.

So: yes, it is valid, no, don't use it.

Comment: "If a URI does not contain an authority component"
What does that mean? What is an authority component?

Comment: As per the example given in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3, it looks like authority is equivalent of domain name (with port)