# What's the difference between // and http or https

Tags: html, http, https, href

I could only find answers about http and https comparison but I would like to ask: Is there any difference if I will use in code `//` rather than `https://`? (In addition to reducing the code)

For example:

```
<a href="//website.com">test></a>
```

And:

```
<a href="https://website.com">test></a>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523318/is-a-url-with-in-the-path-section-valid and specially https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743247/types-of-urls

Answer (score 1):

In a URL, `//` means "current protocol"; either http or https depending on which you're currently using.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be crystal clear, the difference between using `//` rather than `https://` is that the second specifies the protocol (https), whereas the first uses the current protocol (which could be `http` or `https`, like wizzwizz4 answered). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743247/types-of-urls) for more details